# insertRowsAtIndexPaths UITableview issue

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview, nsindexpath

I am having a table with 3 rows with right arrow button with tag values 0,1,2.while clicking that right arrow in first row,It will display another 2 more rows like dropdown.I inserted two rows using the following code.But how to change the tag values after insertion of rows like 0,1,2,3,4.I have done table reload also.But i want to show with down arrow(previously selected button).So it is not working.

```
tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: .Left)
```

This is how I handled click action of that button.

```
func cellExpandAction(sender: AnyObject){

    let prod = dataArray[sender.tag]
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: sender.tag, inSection: 1)

let selectedCell:OtherCell = tblMenu.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! OtherCell
        if(prod.canBeExpanded)
        {
            if(prod.isExpanded){
                self.collapseCellsFromIndexOf(prod, indexPath: indexPath, tableView: tblMenu)
                selectedCell.btnArrow.selected = false
            }
            else{
                selectedCell.btnArrow.selected = true
                self.expandCellsFromIndexOf(prod, indexPath: indexPath, tableView: tblMenu)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you show code where you handle tap on the button?

Comment: What is the exact problem you are having? Does your code crash? Does your code not compile? Please add the full method you are having a problem in and also add the exact error message.

Comment: You should try not to rely on tags.

Comment: i think you should use RATreeView to achieve what you want easily.